# Sort numpy.array rows by indices

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have 2D `numpy.array` and a tuple of indices:

```
a = array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]])
ix = (2, 0, 3, 1)
```

How can I sort array's rows by the indices? Expected result:

```
array([[1, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1]])
```

I tried using `numpy.take`, but it works as I expect only with 1D arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can in fact use [`ndarray.take()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.take.html) for this. The trick is to supply the second argument (`axis`):

```
>>> a.take(ix, 0)
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [0, 1]])
```

(Without `axis`, the array is flattened before elements are taken.)

Alternatively:

```
>>> a[ix, ...]
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [0, 1]])
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about the second argument of ``numpy.take``.