# Why does the numpy function `take` change the shape of my array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, scipy

I am trying to calculate which points in my data set (in the shape of a numpy array called "matrix") are closest to a vector (array called "vector") in ndimensional space. Then, I want to extract these same vectors from a data set which is identical to "matrix" but includes additional labels (="matrix_with_labels").

```
vector=([1,2,3,...])
matrix=[[1,2,3,...], [2,4,6,...], ...]]
matrix_with_labels=[[a,1,2,3,...], [b,2,4,6,...], ...]]
```

Thus, I compute the distances between the vector and each item in the matrix:

```
dist=scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(matrix,vector,'euclidean')
```

Then I sort these distances to identify the closest neighbors:

```
sorted_index=np.argsort(dist, axis=0)
```

Then I try to sort the "matrix_with_labels" by "sorted_index", using `numpy.take` as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699811/sort-numpy-array-rows-by-indices) on SO.

```
result= matrix_with_labels.take(sorted_index, 0)
```

The outcome looks just fine until I try to process it further - it seems to have changed shape:

```
print result.shape
(20, 1, 11)
```

When I look at the shape of the initial "matrix_with_labels", however:

```
matrix_with_labels.shape
(20, 11)
```

The documentation on [take](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.take.html#numpy.take) says:

> subarray : ndarray
>   The returned array has the same type as a.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "same type" doesn't mean "same shape".

Comment: What is the `shape` of `dist` and `x` (aka `sorted_index`)?  `matrix_with_labels.take(x, 0)` is the same as `matrix_with_labels[x,:]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're starting with a `(20, 11)` shape, I think the only way to get a `(20, 1, 11)` shape is if `x` has shape `(1, 11)`.

Try `result = matrix_with_labels.take(x.reshape(-1), 0)`.