# How to simplify a numpy array indexing?

Tags: numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array:

```
a = np.array([
        [4, 7, 3],
        [7, 1, 8],
        [9, 3, 2],
    ])
```

and another index array:

```
I = np.array([
        [2, 1, 0],
        [1, 2, 0],
        [0, 2, 1],
    ])
```

I want to rearrange each row of `a` following each row of `I`, and I can do it like following:

```
b = a[np.arange(3).reshape(-1, 1), I]
```

and get the result:

```
[[3 7 4]
 [1 8 7]
 [9 2 3]]
```

But I think using  `np.arange(3).reshape(-1, 1)` is too ugly. Does there exist any simpler code to finish this thing?

Comment: Is `np.arrange(3)[:, None]` less uggly than the reshape? If you consider the amount of lines that takes to do that iteratively I wouldn't consider ir *uggly*. You could always create a function to make it less *uggly*.

Comment: Another possible duplicate that uses `np.take` [Sort numpy.array rows by indices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699811/sort-numpy-array-rows-by-indices)

Comment: I routinely use `arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)` to make a test array.